# RKJSONParserJSONKit not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, restkit

I'm trying to use JSON parsing from RestKit, but I'm receiving 
the following compile time error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKJSONParserJSONKit", referenced from: 
  objc-class-ref in FloorMapLoaderViewController.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

RestKit works ok, this being the only error I've seen so far. 
This is my import line:

```
#import <RestKit/Support/JSON/JSONKit/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h>
```

edit:
oddly, it fails to compile only if I try to create a parser like so:

```
 RKJSONParserJSONKit *parser = [RKJSONParserJSONKit new];
```

Commenting out this line allows for compilation, but I do need to instance a parser.

How can I fix this error? 
Thank you.

Comment: I will be suggesting you to use - NSJSONSerialization instead of RKJSONParserJSONKit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing means that your source code can see the API, so the IDE knows how to auto-complete and so that the compiler knows how to generate the right object code.

You have a linker error.  Once your own code is compiled, it has to all be bundled together with all the code it is dependent on (not counting dynamically linked system libraries).  Your linker is telling you that after bundled everything it can find together, not all of it is there.

What you need to do is go to the target you are building, select the *Build Phases* tab, and add the necessary library to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.